# WordPress REST Api: update user

Tags: users, api, rest-api, authorization

I have created an user via wordpress api, then after registration, I save user's username and password into the sessionStorage, and then, finaly, try to edit user's profile. Here's my post request data

```
POST /wp-json/wp/v2/users?context=edit HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 292
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Authorization: Bearer ********************************************************************************************************
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

POST Body

"postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "text": "{\"first_name\":\"Foo\",\"last_name\":\"Bar\",\"city\":\"Belgrade\",\"zip\":11000,\"address\":\"Foobar 7\",\"email\":\"someemail@gmail.com\",\"username\":\"foobar\",\"name\":\"Foo Bar\",\"nickname\":\"Foo Bar\",\"password\":\"myexamplepass\",\"context\":\"edit\",\"meta\":{\"city\":\"Belgrade\",\"zip\":11000,\"address\":\"FooBar 17\"}}"
          }
```

Now, with that request, I get *{"code":"rest_cannot_create_user","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create new users.","data":{"status":403}}*

Response is:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create_user",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create new users.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to create a post with that very user, via postman, it works properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My REST URL was wrong - I didn't add the userid to the url. Proper REST URL should be: */wp-json/wp/v2/users/30/* where 30 should be changed with user's id.